# Get values of textboxes created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of textboxes created dynamically accroding to the user selection on aspx page.

I want to get and store into an array the value of these using Jquery, javascript.

how can i do that?

is it possible to loop through all the textboxes in a page?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to succinctly grab all the values:

```
var values = $("input[type=text]").map(function() {
    return this.value; // or $(this).val()
}).get();
```

Loop over all textboxes using [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
var values = [];
$("input[type=text]").each(function() {
    values.push(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = new Array();
$(":text").each(function(){
    values.push ( this.value );
});
```